# How do I start a combo?

Tags: remember-me

Playing through the first episodes of "Remember Me", I've unlocked two combos - a 3-hit one, and a 5-hit one.

Trouble is, I'm not sure how to actually *trigger* them. Left Mouse Button seems to punch, and Right Mouse Button seems to kick, but beyond that, the only way I've managed to initiate combos is by button-mashing (or mouse-mashing, in my case).

What is the *actual* way to trigger combos?

And Corollary: "What determines which combo I'm using?"

Comment: I have the exact problem, luckily I managed to move along the game but not for too long as I got stuck in a fight which looks like it requires killing enemies too fast. I think X refers to Left Mouse Button as referred in the previous answer, but I don't know if you should mash or not, I think the secret is in timing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After playing around with it for another hour or so, I've gotten a better grasp on the combat mechanics.

[image]

Nilin has only two "basic" attacks, a Punch (Default LMB / X), and a Kick (Default RMB).

Each individual Pressen is either a "Punch Variant" (identified with P, above) or a "Kick Variant" (likewise with K). While you can set any pressen in any combo, you can only put P pressens in P combo slots, and K pressens in K's.

Combos are set groupings of P and K Pressens -- The 3-hit combo is P - P - P, and the 5-hit combo is K-P-K-P-K

Do note that you can only continue your combo if you're pressing the appropriate P or K button. So you do have to keep track of where you are in the combo, and aren't able to simply button mash your way to victory.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to program your combos. Push <kbd>Select</kbd> (consoles) or <kbd>Tab</kbd> (PC) and choose the Combo Lab. There you want to assign various pressens (combo types: attack, heal, cool down, etc) to your combos. Once you have done that you can go and use them in combat.

The button sequence for each combo is fixed, but the skills can be changed to create various effects in battle.

Basic combo:

- PC: <kbd>LMB</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>
- Xbox 360: <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>
- PlayStation 3: <kbd>▢</kbd><kbd>▢</kbd><kbd>▢</kbd>

To any combo first start with the opening attack. When that attack hits the enemy, you need to then hit the next button in the sequence. You will see highlighted on the combo meter below if you succeed. Then follow up on the next strike with the last button. And you will have succeeded with a 3 hit combo!

Comment: But what is `X` in this case? And where is this listed?

Comment: @RavenDreamer It's all listed in the combo lab.

Comment: I can't find it in the PC version. Guess which one I'm playing on? :/

Comment: @RavenDreamer Ah. Have you tried the ESC or the F-keys to find the menu?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Like I said, triggering the combos is just a matter of when you hit an enemy, hit the next button in the combo chain.

Comment: Ah, I see my comment was ambiguous. I'm well-versed in the combat lab. What I *can't* find is an indicator of what buttons result in the start of which combos.

Comment: Figured it out. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Punches are usually your strongest attack and a good strategy for your kicks on the right side that you place in your combos on the left is to make every other combo button a purple regen followed by a heal, that way you will always be regenerating special power as well as health in order to easily get through the toughest settings on this game.  Remember to avoid as many red exclamation points as possible with your evade button and shoot distanced enemies with your blaster in between evasions and combo attacks.  Also the game will direct you mainly through your story line but explore! You will increase your health and force power which makes tough fights easy.  If bosses are blocking, try yo complete combos to life back up and decrease your special power time.